# Extract the data rich nodes of a webpage using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tags, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Extract the data rich nodes of a web page using  beautifulsoup in python ,Is there a way to count the frequency of the tags in the page,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.amazon.in"
r = requests.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Now I want to  count the frequency of all the tags in html obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [**`collection.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get counts of `tags` that are instance of `bs4.element.Tag`.

```
from collections import Counter
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.amazon.in"
r = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
Counter(tag.name for tag in html.descendants if isinstance(tag, bs4.element.Tag))
```

**output**

```
Counter({'div': 462, 'a': 448, 'span': 395, 'li': 288, 'br': 78, 'img': 60, 'td': 57, 'script': 48, 'ul': 39, 'option': 27, 'tr': 22, 'table': 17, 'meta': 13, 'map': 12, 'area': 12, 'link': 11, 'style': 10, 'p': 10, 'b': 9, 'h2': 7, 'strong': 5, 'input': 2, 'body': 1, 'title': 1, 'html': 1, 'header': 1, 'form': 1, 'head': 1, 'label': 1, 'select': 1})
```